# Restructure Polymer Starter Kit to a single element

Tags: polymer

How do i go from the auto-binding template to a 'my-app' structure and still keep the build structure, web sync, etc. working?

```
<body unresolved>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

Comment: Looking at code from the [psk2 branch](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/tree/psk2) of the psk repo, it seems the whole project will be migrated to a 'single element' structure for version 2, frankly speaking, I think it's better to wait till the project gets there and work on the current version in a way that can be easily migrated to version 2

Comment: Tx for the reply..i will wait then